# Use python fsolve for solving equations with 2-D input variables

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

By knowing that fsolve function can be easily applied using the following method:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def solve(var):
    x = var[0]
    y = var[1]
    
    f = np.zeros(2)
    f[0] = x+y-a
    f[1] = 3*x+7*y-10
    return f
a = 2
var = fsolve(solve, np.zeros(2))
print(var)
```

BUT, how can I use fsolve function if `a` be a 2-D matrix like the following code (in comparison of the above code, just `a` has changed):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def solve(var):
    x = var[0]
    y = var[1]
    
    f = np.zeros(2)
    f[0] = x+y-a
    f[1] = 3*x+7*y-10
    return f
a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])
var = fsolve(solve, np.zeros(2))
print(var)
```

**Edit:**

What I want can be calculated using the following method. But is it possible to do it without using the `for` loops? (maybe if we define the `var[0,:]` and `var[1,:]` instead of `var[0]` and `var[1]`, the problem would be solved)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def solve(var):
    x = var[0]
    y = var[1]
    
    f = np.zeros(2)
    f[0] = x+y-a
    f[1] = 3*x+7*y-10
    return f
a1 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
for a2 in a1:
    for a3 in a2:
        a=a3
        var = fsolve(solve, np.zeros(2))
        print(var)
```

Comment: The way it currently stands, it cannot work. Consider what you are asking the function to do: in function `solve()`, you have:
```
f = np.zeros(2)
f[0] = x+y-a
```
Thus, you expect `f` to be an array of two scalars, but you're using `a` as a 2x2 matrix, which will make `f[0]` a 2x2 matrix, which is a no-go.

It would help if you explained what it is that you want the code to do, i.e. explain the math behind the implementation.

Comment: my real code is so complicated I tried to simplify my problem for this post. I am working on a numerical project. In this project, I have more than 1000 cells, and the value of each cell changes at each timestep. I need to import all of my variables simultaneously into the fsolve function and get results for each cell. I don't want to use two ```for``` loops.

Comment: What don't you understand about `A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument, and returns a value of the same length.`?

Comment: @hpaulj I think maybe it is not true to say that `A function that takes at least one (possibly vector) argument`, because we could easily calculate the values of a function (for instance `f(x)=x^2`) with `x = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])` input

Comment: The first thing `fsolve` does (one function level down) is `x0 = asarray(x0).flatten()`.  Many of the `scipy` 'solvers' use Fortran/C libraries that aren't multi-dimensional.

Comment: How can I change the code to solve it if `a` would be a vector `a = np.array([1,2])`?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid *for* loops, you can use `numpy.vectorize`:

```
def func(x,a):
  return [x[0]+x[1]-a, 3*x[0]+7*x[1]-10]
def solve(var, a):
  sol = fsolve(func, x0=var, args=(a))
  return sol

a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])
vfunc = np.vectorize(solve, excluded=['var'], otypes=[list])
sol = vfunc(var=np.zeros(2), a=a)
```